# I tried applying Lagrange's theorem to an example and it did not work

Tags: group-theory

I know I am probably missing something simple but I just can't find my error.

From Lagrange's theorem it follows that for every element $a$ of the group $G, a^{|G|} = e$ but when I thought about the Group $F_3$ (I mean the residual class, since $3$ is prime it is a group) it did not work: $$[2]^3=[8]=[2] \neq [1].$$

I am learning this in a rushed IT security introduction, so I am not deep into the matter.

Comment: $F_3$ is under addition, not multiplication. So $[2]*3=[6]=[0]$.

Comment: In the group $F_3$, the operation is addition, not multiplication... Instead, you should write $[2]^3=[2+2+2]=[6]=[0]$.

Answer (score 4):

The operation is *additive*; you should, therefore, have

$$\begin{align}
[2]+[2]+[2]&=3[2]\\
&=[3\times 2]\\
&=[6]\\
&=[0],
\end{align}$$

where $[0]$ is the identity of the group.